# Switch(event.type) not working & timer not showing

Tags: c++, c, timer, sdl

I am following a french tutorial in order to learn C programming, and I am right now facing the exercice of making a timer, which updates every 100 milliseconds. Since the tutorial is for SDL and I am using SDL2, I am mixing it with some knowledge found on Internet. 
If anyone here has time and know some SDL2/SDL_TTF, can you try to solve this ? 
The function nulos() is a way to find it the initialization worked out. 
To resume, my two problems are : the window closes itself at about 2 seconds and I can't click on the close option, and the second one is my text not showing.

Have a Good Day !

```
int compteur()
{
    SDL_Window      *pWindow = NULL;
    SDL_Renderer    *pRenderer = NULL;
    SDL_Texture     *pTexture = NULL;
    SDL_Surface     *pSurface = NULL;
    SDL_Surface     *pTexte = NULL;
    SDL_Event       event;
    TTF_Font        *pFont = NULL;
    SDL_Color       black = {0, 0, 0};
    SDL_Color       white = {255, 255, 255};
    SDL_Rect        position = {200, 200, 0, 0};

    int             bPlay = 1;
    int             tempsActuel = 0;
    int             tempsPrecedent = 0;
    int             compteur = 0;
    char            temps[20];
    temps[0] = '\0';

    if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO | SDL_INIT_TIMER) != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Erreur SDL_Init : %s ", SDL_GetError());
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    TTF_Init();

    pWindow = SDL_CreateWindow("COMPTEUR.C", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, WIDTH, HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    pRenderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(pWindow, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
    pSurface = SDL_GetWindowSurface(pWindow);
    if(nulos(pWindow, pRenderer, pSurface) != 0)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    pFont = TTF_OpenFont("images/Gabriola.ttf", 40);
    if(pFont == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error TTF_OpenFont : %s ", TTF_GetError());
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    TTF_SetFontStyle(pFont, TTF_STYLE_ITALIC | TTF_STYLE_UNDERLINE);

    tempsActuel = SDL_GetTicks();
    sprintf(temps, "Temps : %d", compteur);
    pTexte = TTF_RenderText_Shaded(pFont, temps, black, white);

    while(bPlay != 0)
    {
        SDL_WaitEvent(&event);
        switch(event.type)
        {
            case SDL_QUIT:
                bPlay = 0;
                break;
        }

        SDL_FillRect(pSurface, NULL, SDL_MapRGB(pSurface->format, black.r, black.g, black.b));
        SDL_RenderClear(pRenderer);

        tempsActuel = SDL_GetTicks();
        if(tempsActuel - tempsPrecedent >= 100)
        {
            compteur += 100;
            sprintf(temps, "Temps : %d", compteur);
            pTexte = TTF_RenderText_Shaded(pFont, temps, black, white);
            tempsPrecedent = tempsActuel;
        }

        SDL_BlitSurface(pTexte, NULL, pSurface, &position);
        SDL_FreeSurface(pTexte);
        pTexture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(pRenderer, pSurface);
        SDL_RenderCopy(pRenderer, pTexture, NULL, NULL);
        SDL_RenderClear(pRenderer);
    }

    SDL_DestroyRenderer(pRenderer);
    SDL_FreeSurface(pSurface);
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(pRenderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(pWindow);
    TTF_Quit();
    SDL_Quit();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

```
int nulos(SDL_Window *w, SDL_Renderer *r, SDL_Surface *s)
{
    if(w == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Erreur SDL_CreateWindow : %s ", SDL_GetError());
        return -1;
    }
    else if(r == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Erreur SDL_CreateRenderer : %s ", SDL_GetError());
        return -1;
    }
    else if(s == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Erreur SDL_GetWindowSurface : %s ", SDL_GetError());
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As a side point you do not need to test if nulos() != 0. In C 0 => false so you can just write if(nulos(pWindow, pRenderer, pSurface)). If the return value is zero this is false so no exit. If the return value is anything else the condition evaluates to true so you will exit the program. Depending on your system 'opaque' calls like this can cause problems. Better to declare a variable int  return_value; set return_value = nulos(...); and the check if (return_value); That might even solve your problem.

Comment: @JonGuiton : I decided to abandon nulos() just to see, as creating a int value does not work. My program shows nothing and stops at around 2 seconds, again. I have deleted nulos() and just put this line :                       
       if(pWindow == NULL || pRenderer == NULL || pSurface == NULL)
 {
  fprintf(stderr, "Erreur : %s ", SDL_GetError());
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
 }

Answer (score 0):

Okay I have resolved the first problem, it was just a careless mistake. It should have been :

```
SDL_RenderPresent(pRenderer);
```

Instead of

```
SDL_RenderClear(pRenderer);
```

However the window still closes by itself...

Answer (score 0):

Okay I did it ! For anyone wondering, here's the "good" programming. I put a SDL_PollEvent and moved pTexte elsewhere :

```
#include "main.h"

int compteur()
{
    SDL_Window      *pWindow = NULL;
    SDL_Renderer    *pRenderer = NULL;
    SDL_Texture     *pTexture = NULL;
    SDL_Surface     *pSurface = NULL;
    SDL_Surface     *pTexte = NULL;
    SDL_Event       event;
    TTF_Font        *pFont = NULL;
    SDL_Color       black = {0, 0, 0};
    SDL_Color       white = {255, 255, 255};
    SDL_Rect        position;
    SDL_bool        bQuit = SDL_FALSE;

    int             tempsActuel = 0;
    int             tempsPrecedent = 0;
    int             compteur = 0;
    char            temps[20];
    temps[0] = '\0';

    if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Erreur SDL_Init : %s ", SDL_GetError());
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    TTF_Init();

    pWindow = SDL_CreateWindow("COMPTEUR.C", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, WIDTH, HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    pRenderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(pWindow, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
    SDL_RenderClear(pRenderer);
    pSurface = SDL_GetWindowSurface(pWindow);

    if(pWindow == NULL || pRenderer == NULL || pSurface == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Erreur : %s ", SDL_GetError());
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    pFont = TTF_OpenFont("images/Gabriola.ttf", 40); 
    if(pFont == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error TTF_OpenFont : %s ", TTF_GetError());
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    TTF_SetFontStyle(pFont, TTF_STYLE_ITALIC | TTF_STYLE_UNDERLINE);

    tempsActuel = SDL_GetTicks();
    sprintf(temps, "Temps : %d", compteur);
    pTexte = TTF_RenderText_Shaded(pFont, temps, black, white);
    if(pTexte == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error TTF_RenderText_Shaded : %s ", TTF_GetError());
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while(!bQuit) //SDL_FALSE == 0
    {
        while(SDL_PollEvent(&event))
        {
            switch(event.type)
            {
                case SDL_QUIT:
                    bQuit = SDL_TRUE;
                    break; 
            }
        }
        tempsActuel = SDL_GetTicks();
        if(tempsActuel - tempsPrecedent >= 100)
        {
            compteur += 100;
            sprintf(temps, "Temps : %d", compteur);
            tempsPrecedent = tempsActuel;
        }

        position.x = 180;
        position.y = 210;

        pTexte = TTF_RenderText_Shaded(pFont, temps, white, black);
        SDL_FillRect(pSurface, NULL, SDL_MapRGB(pSurface->format, black.r, black.g, black.b));      
        SDL_BlitSurface(pTexte, NULL, pSurface, &position);
        SDL_FreeSurface(pTexte);

        pTexture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(pRenderer, pSurface);
        if(pTexture == NULL)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface : %s ", SDL_GetError());
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        SDL_RenderCopy(pRenderer, pTexture, NULL, NULL);
        SDL_RenderPresent(pRenderer);
    }

    SDL_Delay(20);
    SDL_FreeSurface(pSurface);
    if(pTexture != NULL)
        SDL_DestroyTexture(pTexture);
    if(pRenderer != NULL)
        SDL_DestroyRenderer(pRenderer);
    if(pWindow != NULL)
        SDL_DestroyWindow(pWindow);
    TTF_Quit();
    SDL_Quit();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```